# Problem connecting to the "Primary" of the replica set in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have created a MongoDB replica set in command line. They are running in ports 47017,47018,47019. When I do a

```
mongo --port 47017
```

It always tends to connect to the "Secondary" member of the replica set

```
$ mongo --port 47017
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:47017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
MongoDB server version: 4.2.6
s1:SECONDARY>
```

Why is it always connecting to the Secondary and not to the primary ? Is there any setting that should be enabled ?

Comment: Try this way as specified in the [mongo shell documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/index.html): _To connect mongo shell to a replica set, you can specify in the connection string the replica set members and name:_

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to a single node. You need to specify that you want to connect to the replica set by passing the replica set name in the arguments. e.g.

```
mongo "mongodb://127.0.0.1:47017,127.0.0.1:47018,127.0.0.0.1:47019/?replicaSet=replA"
```

Here the replica set name is **replA**. Strictly speaking you don't need to specify the whole seed list. As long as you can connect to any member and you specify the replica set name then the replica set will automatically route you to the primary. We specify a complete seedlist because this allows the client to try all members in case one of them is not available.

See the docs for [Connecting to a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#connect-to-a-mongodb-replica-set) for a complete description.